# PLC modbus datalogger that can push data to a web server

Tags: modbus, plc

We are looking for a data logger to connect to a PLC through Modbus TCP or RTU.  I have found several of these on the market, but I need the ability to post the data back to a web server.  Basically we have a website that uses a graph to show the current values from the PLC over time and this data shouldn’t be more than a few seconds old.  We have used a raspberry pi, but we are looking for alternatives for a more industrial environment.

Critical features
1.  If the connection is lost, then the data that has been logged since the last connection should be sent up.
2.  A backup of the logged data should be stored on the device
3.  Use some type of frequent update mechanism to send data to the server like a html post.

I have only found one device and I wonder if Im using the wrong search terms/lingo or if COT devices do not exist with these features.

Answer (score 3):

I did a similar project recently  using a B&R Plc,  and the AsHTTP library.  It was able to do http put / get requests directly to a resource on the Web.  (I've seen the term rest  API used in the Web world)  You could write your own code to buffer and store the data locally on flash memory in case it disconnects from the net.

Also B&R lets you use ModbusTCP for free directly through the ethernet port.

I've never used a "data logger" standalone device,  but this is one option.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate using an Omron NJ Series PLC with SQL Connection capabilities. This PLC could grab any data on another PLC through EtherNet/IP. From there, it has the ability to log to an SQL Server.

A very useful feature that I have made extensive use of is the spool function. If the connection between the NJ and the SQL Database is broken, the NJ will retain the data that wasn't logged in its own memory and insert it automatically once the connection is reestablished.

https://industrial.omron.ca/en/products/nj5-database-connection